# Bash: copy a file to all home directories

Tags: bash, file, copy, home-directory

I have to copy (overwrite if it already exists) a file to all the home directories of users members of a same group ("students").

I found a script that I tried to adapt to my context (I have LDAP users instead of /etc/passwd so I used getent passwd to fetch usernames).

Here it is the script (cp2stud.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

# subdirectory of /home/uid
DIR=".eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration"

# the file to copy
FILE="/home/admin/tmp/config.ini"

# location of home dirs
UHOME="/home" 

# GID of "students" group
USERS_GID=10004

# get list of users having same GID
_USERS="$(getent passwd | awk -F ':' '{if ( $4 == $USERS_GID ) print $1 }')"

for u in $_USERS
do
   _dir="${UHOME}/${u}/${DIR}"
   if [ -d "$_dir" ]
   then
     yes | /bin/cp -v "$FILE" "$_dir"
     chown $(id -un $u):students "$_dir/${FILE}"
   fi
done
```

When i try to launch it:

```
$ sudo cp2stud.sh
```

I get nothing.

Where I am mistaking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo bash -x cp2stud.sh` ?  The `-x` traces each command to stdout.

Comment: Is your variable usage of $USERS_GID with awk correct?

Comment: sudo bash -x cp2stud.sh

+ DIR=
+ FILE=/skole/tjener/home0/frank/config.ini
+ UHOME=/skole/tjener/home0
+ STUD_GID=10004
++ awk -F : '{if ( $4 == $STUD_GID ) print $1 }'
++ getent passwd
+ _USERS=

Comment: You were given 3 answers to this question. Are any of them acceptable? If not, could you indicate why?

Answer (score 1):

```
_USERS="$(getent passwd | awk -v X="$USERS_GID" -F ':' '{if ( $4 == X ) print $1 }')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
...
export USERS_GID=10004

_USERS=$(getent passwd | awk -F ':' '{if ( $4 == ENVIRON["USERS_GID"] ) print $1 }')
...
```

You could also do something like this:

```
...

USERS_GID=10004

_USERS=$(getent passwd | awk -F ':' -v gid=$USERS_GID '{if ( $4 == gid ) print $1 }')
...
```

Or just:

```
...

_USERS=$(getent passwd | awk -F ':' -v gid=10004 '{if ( $4 == gid ) print $1 }')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
DIR=".eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration"
FILE="/home/admin/tmp/config.ini"

UHOME="/home"
USERS_GID=10004
GRP_NAME=students
FILENAME=$(basename $FILE)


_USERS="$(getent passwd | awk -v X="$USERS_GID" -F ':' '{if ( $4 == X ) print $1 }')"

for u in $_USERS
do
  _dir="${UHOME}/${u}/${DIR}"
  if [ -d "$_dir" ]
  then
      yes | /bin/cp -v "$FILE" "$_dir"
      chown -v $(id -un $u):$GRP_NAME "${UHOME}/${u}/${DIR}${FILENAME}"
  fi
done
```